# Java For Loop Ignores i Position when Letter of Array is the Same

Tags: java, string, loops, for-loop, char

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.*;

public class testing {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        char[] engArray = {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I'};
        String stringEngArray = String.valueOf(engArray);

        System.out.println("Text input");
        String input2 = input.nextLine().toUpperCase();

        int inputedOffset = 4;

        char[] finalArray = inpute2.toCharArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < inputedText.length(); i++) {
            int arrayPosition = inpute2.indexOf(inputedText.charAt(i));
            int engPosition = stringEngArray.indexOf(inputedText.charAt(i));
            int test = (arrayPosition % inputedOffset);
            int newTest = engPosition+test;
            finalArray[i] = engArray[newTest];

        }
        String output = new String(finalArray);
        System.out.println(output);

    }
}
```

I am trying to change the inputted by user text in order to accomplish some basic encryption.

When i enter abcd or tesla or world the output works as expected and is changing to aceg to tfuoa to wptod
The problem occurs when i am entering aaaa or aabbcc or generally when a letter is repeated on the text. At the second time the for loop finds the same letter it just uses the array position of the 1st read similar letter.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because `inputedText.indexOf(inputedText.charAt(i));`, this is what's causing it to return the same index, since it will just grab the first occurance of `a` which will be the same for every `a` character.

You're trying to get the array position, but why are you doing it this way when the arrayposition is already the variable `i`?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    char[] engArray = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N',
            'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z' };
    String stringEngArray = String.valueOf(engArray);

    System.out.println("Text input");
    String inputedText = input.nextLine().toUpperCase();

    int inputedOffset = 4;

    char[] finalArray = inputedText.toCharArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < inputedText.length(); i++) {
        int engPosition = stringEngArray.indexOf(inputedText.charAt(i));
        int test = (i % inputedOffset);
        int newTest = engPosition + test;
        finalArray[i] = engArray[newTest];

    }
    String output = new String(finalArray);
    System.out.println(output);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You are using `indexOf()` to get the arrayposition. This will always return the position of the first occurrence of that character in the string.
You can simply use `i` as the arrayposition.